# List all document keys in a Solr index for the purpose of database synchronisation

Tags: solr, solrj, dataimporthandler

I need to synchronize a Solr index with a database table. At any given time, the Solr index may need to have documents added or removed. The nature of the database prevents the Data Import Handler's Delta Import functionality from being able to detect changes.

My proposed solution was to retrieve a list of all primary keys of the database table and all unique keys of the Solr index (which contain the same integer value) and compare these lists. I would use SolrJ for this.

However, to get all Solr documents requires the infamous approach of hard-coding the maximum integer value as the result count limit. Using this approach seems to be frowned upon. Does my situation have cause to ignore this advice, or is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute two queries to list all keys from solr in one batch: first with rows=0, you will get a number of hits, second with that number as rows parameter. Its not very optmimal solution, but works. 
Second possibility is to store update date in solr index, and fetch only changed documents from last synchronisation.